# datetime column from MySql return as chr using dbGetQuery()

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I send a query to a MySql database using RMySQL package and the returned result for a column that is defined as datetime is chr

```
library(RMySQL)
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'user', password = "pass",
                 host = 'localhost', dbname = 'database')
AA <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from table where symbol = 'A'")
```

Comment: That is known limitation in `RMySQL`. Other DB backends like Postgres and `RPostgreSQL` have supported Datetime for a decade or close enough to it.

Comment: (You don't want to know the pain of SQL Server formats and such.) It should be simple enough to clean-up your query with a call such as `ret[isdate] <- lapply(ret[isdate], function(d) as.POSIXct(d, format="..."))` with an update to `format=` for the specific output. (`isdate` is a vector of columns you know to convert.)